# Evernote Zapier

Tags: evernote, zapier, smartsheet-api

I use Evernote in meetings every day and when I have a task I tag the task with a checkbox.  What I would like to do is to use Zapier to read new Evernote notes and if there is a checkbox in a note I would like for the item to appear in my ToDo list in Smartsheet.  From there I would be able to assign tasks etc which would greatly help me manage tasks for myself and my team.

I wrote the Evernote team to understand how checkboxes are coded and below is the reply:

[Answer from Evernote Help](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aujga.png)

The Zapier team has entered this as a feature request but it seems like I should be able to write something in the Formatter and have it do this now.  After seeing the response from Evernote the Zapier team suggested I post the question here.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Zapier offers an action called "Filter by Zapier". Use it just after your trigger and check if:

- Content HTML
- (text) contains
- en-todo checked="true"

Check [this screenshot](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/g8xhs0ghuh2j1u9/Capture%20d%E2%80%99%C3%A9cran%202019-01-03%20%C3%A0%2000.57.19.png?dl=0&m=) to see how it looks like in Zapier ;)

Comment: Thank you @DFATPUNK that worked, I think I had tried to find the tag previously but for an unchecked box it is en-todo checked="false" and because I used "true" it must have failed.  The next step for me will be to finalize my zap by just grabbing the text after the checkbox.  Thanks again for the help.

Comment: Awesome :) Could you check your thread as answered? I may be able to help you with your next step if you elaborate a bit more.

Comment: Hey there, I absolutely can check it but have one more question before I do.  My evernote HTML looks like this:   
<!DOCTYPE en-note SYSTEM "http://xml.evernote.com/pub/enml2.dtd"><en-note><div><en-todo checked="false" />Test Event<br /> - What I want to grab is right after "false" /> until the next <br /> and I want this to create a Smartsheet line for each section of text.  I cannot seem to figure out how to do this part.

Comment: You must use Formatter by Zapier -> Split Text. Select your content HTML and type ``" />`` as separator and select ``All (as separate item)``. Then, repeat this step with the "Test Event<br />" bit and type ``<br />`` in the separator field. It will return "Test Event" alone.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you this answered it @DFATPUNK.  I now have a Zap that creates tasks in Smartsheet based on boxes placed in a document.

If I need to do anything else to mark this as answered please let me know.

Comment: It’s all good Donald, glad your first thread on Stack Overflow proved to be helpful. Happy zaping ;)